# to get data in a modal in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Is there any way to get the data inside a modal? I know that it is possible to work with this through Jquery, but I would like to know if there is any way to work with Laravel itself. In a view, we can do this:

`return view ('admin/users/index', ['datas1' => $ datas1, 'datas2' => $datas2];`

but for a modal, is it possible to do something like this? to send my data through the controller and within my modal I check if this data are coming empty or filled, as this answer I just want to show different things, like this:

```
 $dep = User::query()->where('dep_link', $id)->get();
 return['status' => 'success', 'dep' => $dep];
```

only my validation in the modal:

```
      <div class="row" style="padding: 28px 20px;">
            <div class="col-12">
                 @if(empty($dep))
                     <div class="position-relative">
                          <label for="rg_titular">Selecione o RG do titular (.png .jpg .pdf)</label><br>
                          <input type="file" name="rg_titular" class="file-input"/>
                          <button type="button" class="file-button">Selecionar arquivo</button>
                          <span class="text-arquivo">Arquivo selecionado!</span>    
                     </div>                                                 
                 @else
                          <a href="link" target="_blank">
                               Visualizar RG do titular
                          </a>
                  @endif
           </div>
     </div>
```

Is there any way I can get this data inside the modal window and work with them? I just want to check if it's coming empty or not, that's all.

Comment: where do you write modal? in blade?

Comment: Yes, my modal is on the blade for her. I have my index and the modal separately

Answer (score 0):

You can write a view composer for the modal blade file.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers

In your service provider (app, or a custom one you make)

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('myBladeFileName', function ($view) {
        $activeUsers = \App\User::where('active', true)->get();

        $view->with(compact('activeUsers'));
    });
}
```